# BETWEEN array dates

Tags: oracle10g

I have an Oracle DB, and I have a table that shows date ranges:

```
23/12/2011  08/01/2012
06/01/2012  06/01/2012
19/03/2012  19/03/2012
05/04/2012  05/04/2012
06/04/2012  06/04/2012
30/04/2012  30/04/2012
01/05/2012  01/05/2012
02/05/2012  02/05/2012
15/08/2012  15/08/2012
12/10/2012  12/10/2012
01/11/2012  01/11/2012
06/12/2012  06/12/2012
07/12/2012  07/12/2012
08/12/2012  08/12/2012
25/12/2012  25/12/2012
09/01/2013  26/01/2013
20/05/2013  08/06/2013
24/06/2013  13/07/2013
18/01/2013  02/02/2013
24/05/2013  08/06/2013
```

and I want to cross this table with a date, checking that the date is not in a pair of dates of the table, something like this:

```
 select * 
from table
where table.date NOT BETWEEN 
(SELECT DT_START FROM CALENDARIO) AND (SELECT DT_END FROM CALENDARIO))
```

But BETWEEN dont accept arrays as entry, so is there any way to achieve that??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this help you

```
WHERE (d.date1 NOT BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46') 
   OR (d.date2 NOT BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46') 
   OR (d.date3 NOT BETWEEN '2011-11-09 13:08:46' AND '2011-11-11 16:08:46')
```

Comment: The problem is that the response is from a dinamic table, so i can't do an "OR" for each entry.

Comment: you have to store all date in array variable then pass it in query or you have to use loop for execute each query with different date range @Del

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select * 
from table t1
where not exists (
  select null
  from   CALENDARIO
  where  t1.my_date between dt_start and dt_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with @David Aldrige, either NOT EXISTS or NOT IN.

NOT IN and Cross Joining appears to have a better explain plan if it is performance you are worried about http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7159f/6